# Removing encrypted partition on Mac os X does not work

Tags: macos, mac, partitioning, disk-encryption

I have an encrpyted partition on my mac which I'd like to get rid of. I have already backed up my data and have tried several things that I found on the web.

You can find the output of `diskutil cs list` [here](https://gist.github.com/6f281a7f74de2d7331ed).

The first of two things I tried is to delete it with `diskutil cs delete <uuid>`:

```
$ diskutil cs delete 0D4BD22A-79CB-4FD9-BAF1-6F436C79B03F
Started CoreStorage operation
Ejecting Logical Volumes
The volume "(null)" on disk5 couldn't be unmounted
Error: -69886: Invalid request
```

I also tried to run the command on the "subnodes":

```
$ diskutil cs delete 022E5857-4EEB-44B0-8B72-C2A19E5FF7E1
Error deleting CoreStorage Logical Volume Group: Not a valid CoreStorage Logical Volume            Group UUID (-69778)
$ diskutil cs delete A38087E0-BE7F-4E71-A922-B149A60B1BEC
Error deleting CoreStorage Logical Volume Group: Not a valid CoreStorage Logical Volume Group  UUID (-69778)
$ diskutil cs delete 6ED39633-D63A-416E-997D-661E6BF875B6
```

Error deleting CoreStorage Logical Volume Group: Not a valid CoreStorage Logical Volume Group UUID (-69778)

But to no avail.

The other thing was to try to just erase all the data from disk utility itself. It told me:

```
Volume Encrypt and Erase failed with the error: Some information was unavailable during an internal lookup.
```

I wonder what I can do. Basically, this is just a hard disk which I would like to use with no encryption, but I just cannot manage to remove it.

In case it matters, I am using a MacPro 3,1 with a fresh Mountain Lion install.

Comment: Error **-69886** also features in a question in Ask Different: [On 10.7.4 coreStorage unable to create concatenated disk error -69886](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/87308/8546)

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue.  Finally fixed it by booting up a Snow Leopard install disk and erasing the drive from Disk Utility there.

For me, it wasn't that it was mounted and had open files, but that the volume somehow got corrupted and stuck in a limbo state. (It seems to stall while trying to mount a corrupted corestorage volume---won't complete the mount, won't abort the attempt, and won't unmount.)   Since Snow leopard doesn't recognize corestorage in the first place, it didn't get stuck trying to mount it, and can simply erase the volume.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use a form of encryption other than filevault?

From the error you received it seems to me that if you had to use diskutil you will not be able to use cs commands because it tells you it's not valid.

Why not use [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net) after a full backup? To be specific, I would use gparted to delete the offending partitions only then boot back into OSX and use disk utility to expand over the empty space.  And absolutely do a full backup before doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

## Guided by the man page installed with OS X 10.8.3

### Focusing on the Core Storage logical volume group (LVG)

`diskutil coreStorage delete | deleteLVG lvgUUID`

- can apply to a Core Storage *logical volume group*
- can **not** apply to your *physical volume* `022E5857-4EEB-44B0-8B72-C2A19E5FF7E1`
- can **not** apply to your *logical volume family* `A38087E0-BE7F-4E71-A922-B149A60B1BEC`
- can **not** apply to your *logical volume* `6ED39633-D63A-416E-997D-661E6BF875B6`

– whilst you might think of things as nodes, you should **not** think of all four things as equal. For the three attempts that you made on things that are not LVGs, the errors are proper.

When an LVG is deleted, then for that LVG:

> All logical volume families with their logical volumes are removed,
>   the logical volume group is destroyed, and the now-orphaned physical
>   volumes are erased and partition-typed as Journaled HFS+.

---

## Eject or unmount of a Core Storage logical volume (LV)

```
The volume "(null)" on disk5 couldn't be unmounted
Error: -69886: Invalid request
```

So the reason for non-removal was essentially a failure to unmount.

Your disk5 at the time, the *Backup* volume:

```
        Disk:               disk5
        Status:             Online
        Size (Total):       411425443840 B (411.4 GB)
        Size (Converted):   -none-
        Revertible:         No
        LV Name:            Backup
        Content Hint:       Apple_HFS
```

Think beyond processes related to backup. Either of the following commands would reveal open files:

`sudo lsof /dev/disk5`

`sudo lsof /Volumes/Backup`

It's not unusual to find things open by `mds(8)` – the metadata server – longer than expected … but we shouldn't jump to conclusions.